# Allow from a webpage and get immediate response

Tags: html, jakarta-ee

I am new in J2EE. Can anyone tell me:

1. What is one way to allow from a web page to start a long running server process but get an immediate response back?
2. Why are HTML checkboxes sometimes problematic for managing true/false values via form submissions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) It's called [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). This takes considerable resources because of the number of connections the server must keep open. This also sticks users to one server.

2) Programmer error.